# Cruise Control.NET email does not contain error details

Tags: email, cruisecontrol.net

I have configured an email notification when the CC.NET build fails. But the email contains only the failed project name, error code and the count of errors/warnings. It does  not contain the full path of project, file path and the exception message. Interstingly all these information are coming correctly in the web dash bord. I compared the xsl files in the xsl folder in the server and webdashboard folders and found that they are exactly same. Do somebody have some hints as to where to look about?

James

Answer (score 2):

Did you set includeDetails="true" in the configuration of the email publisher:

```
<email includeDetails="TRUE" ... >
```

See [this page](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Email+Publisher) for details.